# How can I see the previous versions numbers of a github repository I have pulled from?

Tags: github

I periodically pull updates from a Github master repository, and was wondering if there was a way to see the record of the Github version numbers of each time I pulled from the master?

Comment: Why not record the version number each time you do a pull?

Comment: I didn't need it until now, and thought that my local repo might contain that information.